# Recommend way to call UWP MessageDialog in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, uwp, messagedialog

I have a MessageDialog with just a single button in my App.xaml.cs 
I wish to use it from other pages.
Several approaches seem to work but as there are subtleties with async and Tasks is a particular one correct?

The following is called with `await App.mymessagebox("A message")`:

```
public static Task async mymessagebox(string the_message)
{
   MessageDialog messagedialog=new MessageDialog(the_message);
   await messagedialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

The following is called with `App the_app=(App)Application.current;
await the_app.mymessagebox("A message");`:

```
public async Task mymessagebox(string the_message)
{
   MessageDialog messagedialog=new MessageDialog(the_message);
   await messagedialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these approaches are functionally equivalent, but the preferred solution would be not to put the methods in the `App` class. Instead, you should create a separate class, which could be even static, that you would use to access these reusable message dialogs. The reason for this is that is separation of concerns. `App` class should only contain code related to the overall app initialization and lifecycle. This is a helper method simplifying the display of dialogs, so it should reside elsewhere:

```
public static DialogHelpers
{
    public static async Task ShowMessageAsync(string message)
    {
       MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(message);
       await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

To adhere to the convention, you should add the `Async` suffix to the name of the method to make it clear the method is `async` and should be `awaited`.

Calling this helper method will now look like this:

```
await DialogHelpers.ShowMessageAsync("Hello, world!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommended way to do this would be to create a client-side dialog or message service that implements an interface:

```
public interface IDialogService
{
    Task ShowMessageAsync(string message);
}

public class DialogService
{
    public async Task ShowMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(message);
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

You could then use this service from any class in your app, .e.g.:

```
IDialogService dialogService = new DialogService();
await dialogService.ShowMessageAsync("message...");
```

If you adopt the recommended MVVM pattern in your app, you could also inject your view models with the interface:

```
public ViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
{
}
```

...and easily mock out the dialog service in your unit tests, e.g.:

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(new MockDialogService());
```

This is not possible if you use a static class or method that you call directly from your view model.